# background.js only works when opened DevTools in chrome extensions

Tags: google-chrome-extension

background.js

```
(function () {
    chrome.windows.onRemoved.removeListener();
    chrome.windows.onRemoved.addListener(function (windowid) {
       alert(0);
    });
})()
```

manifest.json

```
{
    "name": "Merge Windows1",
    "version": "1.0.2",
    "description": "Merges all of the browser's windows into the current window",
    "background": {
        "persistent": false,
        "scripts": ["background.js"]
    },
    "permissions": [
    "input", "http://*/*", "tabs"
    ],
    "manifest_version": 2
}
```

When I opened the DevTools by click "background page" in Chrome Extensions, the code in background.js works and alert when close browser. Otherwise no alert box.

Comment: `removeListener()` should give you an error because you didn't specify a parameter. Remove this line completely, it's not needed with "persistent:false" as the listeners are cleared automatically.

Comment: Thank wOxxOm, it has not been solved. But I tried it in my friend's chrome, it works without devtools opened. We are the same version of Chrome.

Comment: Works for me. Even your original code. You may be doing something wrong. I open a new window (not a tab), and close it, then I see `0` in an alert dialog.

Comment: yes，in my friend's chrome, it works correctly, I can't find out the reason.

Comment: The reason is not in the code, it's fine. It can be a bug in Chrome or maybe something is terribly broken in your browser profile so try in a new one.